# SQL select item in table that are present in an other table with a quantity > 0

Tags: sql

I'm trying this:

Table **sale**

```
id itemid
```

Table **inv**

```
id itemid qty
```

I need to have the number of item in table sale that are in table inv with a qty higher then 0

I try something like this without success

```
SELECT count(sale.id) 
FROM sale 
LEFT OUTER JOIN inv ON sale.itemid = inv.itemid 
WHERE inv.qty > 0
```

The query run forever and never return me a result.
Both table have 1000s of input.

Comment: The number of records is nothing for a DB. Don't you have indexes on these tables?

Comment: I have index on itemid on both table

Comment: I think the important details missing here include which DBMS, the types of the columns and any indexes, the precise numbers of records, the specs and other workloads of the server, etc. Also, why use a `left join` there? If you only care about records with `inv.qty > 0`, then you want an `inner join`; as-is, you pull all the rows in and then implicitly filter them away because for missing columns in `inv` you get a `null` and thus fail to evaluate to _true_ in the `where` clause, but you pointlessly wasted a lot of time along the way (if the optimiser didn't realise this).

Comment: Using left outer join in a huge table takes much longer for query to execute, in this instance i cant see a reason why u cant use Inner Join

Comment: And next, what you probably *actually* want is the total `qty`s from `inv` per item, not each row from each invoice where *that invoice's* item `qty > 0`. So you need to learn to `group` as well as learning what different `join`s do. :P

Comment: @MathieuB Are there any other fields in those two tables?  Perhaps you're joining on the wrong IDs?  *(If `inv` is invoices then perhaps it contains a `sale_id` field, which would be needed to join on the `sale` table?)*

Comment: My server was stuck in some way. I reboot and now query work but result are not as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem here is your LEFT OUTER join.  Change this to an INNER JOIN and you'll only get the records you're looking for.

```
SELECT count(sale.id) 
FROM sale 
INNER JOIN inv ON sale.itemid = inv.itemid 
WHERE inv.qty > 0
```

Comment: I try this approche but I have more result that I have input in my database.

Comment: Let say that In table sale I have 1000 flush input. It return like 9000 in count

Comment: My mistake. I made a mistake in my DB.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select count(*)
from sale
where id IN(SELECT id from inv where qty > 0)
```

This will give you the number of rows in "sale", that have a corresponding "id" value in "inv" with a qty greater than 0.